# Fetch Data from nested props in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am uploading the data from excel file using react-excel-renderer, storing the excel render response containing column & rows response in state and passing to other component.

Expected Use-case result:- I am fetching the data from excel using render storing the values in states(rows). I am passing the state to other component where i need these values to pass in API .

The data stored is in nested form. Can you please let me know how to get data separately stored under array in props. Attached is the screenshot.
[image: Need to get values stored in each array separately]

Excel Render code:-

```
 changeHandler(event) {
        let fileObj = event.target.files[0];
        //just pass the fileObj as parameter
        ExcelRenderer(fileObj, (err, resp) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            this.setState({
              cols: resp.cols,
              rows: resp.rows,
            });

          }
        });
      }
```

Code to fetch the prop data:-

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.props.data.length; i++) {

        let stDate = this.props.data[i].startDate;let TripName = this.props.data[i].TripName;
        let totalFare = this.props.data[i].totalFare;
        let FirstName = this.props.data[i].FirstName;
        let LastName = this.props.data[i].LastName;
        let Currency = this.props.data[i].Currency;
}
```

Comment: write out the data structure you want so we have an idea of input and output. Then we can help you with an easy algorithm.

Comment: provide
- input
- expected result

as @JoeLloyd said

Comment: i have added expected result which i need in my question.. please help

Answer (score 0):

## You can use an Array method

Still not 100% sure what your final data should look like, but it feels like you're using 2 arrays. 1 as the key and 1 as the value.

So to combine these 2 we can use Reduce

```
const keys = data[0];
const values = data[1];
keys.reduce((acc, keys, index) => {
  return {...acc, [key]: values[index]}
}, {})
```

That will return an object of key values.

Comment: Expected Use-case result:- I am fetching the data from excel using render storing the values in states(rows). I am passing the state to other component where i need these values(Air, Test UI Flow etc.)  as body to pass in API .

Comment: Yeaah, the data aggregator above will give you key value stores for all your data instead of an array without context.